# How to resolve Yocto build error for Glib-2.0 for Qt?

Tags: qt5, yocto, glib, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I'm building an image using Yocto for my toradex imx8 board with my QT program. But when I'm running "bitbake displaymod(image name)" I'm getting the following error:
**ERROR: displaymod-1.0.0-r1 do_configure: Error calling /home/user1/oe-core/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-tdx-linux/displaymod/1.0.0-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qmake -makefile -o Makefile  -r   /home/user1/oe-core/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-tdx-linux/displaymod/1.0.0-r1/guiframe.pro  --**

**ERROR: displaymod-1.0.0-r1 do_configure: ExecutionError('/home/user1/oe-core/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-tdx-linux/displaymod/1.0.0-r1/temp/run.do_configure.17576', 1, None, None)**

**ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user1/oe-core/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-tdx-linux/displaymod/1.0.0-r1/temp/log.do_configure.17576**

Log data follows:

| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot

| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase-native_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtdeclarative_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtquickcontrols2_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/glib-2.0/glib-2.0_2.72.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.35.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_11.4.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_11.4.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.67.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/patch/patch_2.7.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot']

| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []

| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['qtbase-native', 'qtbase', 'qtdeclarative', 'qtquickcontrols2', 'glib-2.0', 'glibc', 'gcc-cross-aarch64', 'gcc-runtime', 'quilt-native', 'patch-native', 'pseudo-native', 'xcb-util-wm', 'fontconfig', 'libjpeg-turbo', 'xcb-util-keysyms', 'systemd', 'libxkbcommon', 'libxext', 'sqlite3', 'zlib', 'openssl', 'imx-gpu-viv', 'libxcb', 'xcb-util-image', 'dbus', 'vulkan-headers', 'xcb-util-renderutil', 'libpng', 'libpcre2', 'freetype', 'icu', 'libdrm', 'linux-libc-headers', 'dbus-native', 'zlib-native', 'util-linux', 'libpcre', 'libffi', 'bash-completion', 'libgcc', 'attr-native', 'libtool-native', 'gmp-native', 'zstd-native', 'mpfr-native', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'libmpc-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'flex-native', 'xz-native', 'binutils-cross-aarch64', 'expat', 'acl', 'base-passwd', 'opkg-utils', 'shadow-sysroot', 'kmod', 'libseccomp', 'shadow', 'shadow-native', 'libcap', 'base-files', 'zstd', 'libpam', 'wayland-protocols', 'libxml2', 'wayland', 'xkeyboard-config', 'libx11', 'xorgproto', 'util-macros', 'mesa', 'libxshmfence', 'libxxf86vm', 'libxdmcp', 'libpthread-stubs', 'libxau', 'xcb-proto', 'xcb-util', 'autoconf-archive', 'libsm', 'bzip2', 'libpciaccess', 'glib-2.0-native', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'expat-native', 'libcap-ng', 'ncurses', 'util-linux-libuuid', 'libxcrypt', 'm4-native', 'attr', 'xz', 'flex', 'cracklib', 'python3', 'xtrans', 'libxfixes', 'libxdamage', 'xrandr', 'libice', 'util-linux-native', 'libpcre-native', 'gettext-native', 'libffi-native', 'python3-native', 'cmake-native', 'gdbm', 'readline', 'libtirpc', 'libnsl2', 'libxrandr', 'libxrender', 'util-linux-libuuid-native', 'libpcre2-native', 'libcap-ng-native', 'ncurses-native', 'libtirpc-native', 'gdbm-native', 'bzip2-native', 'openssl-native', 'libnsl2-native', 'readline-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'curl-native', 'perl-native', 'make-native']

| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished

| DEBUG: Executing shell function qmake5_base_preconfigure

| DEBUG: Shell function qmake5_base_preconfigure finished

| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure

**| Project ERROR: glib-2.0 development package not found**

**| ERROR: Error calling /home/user1/oe-core/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-tdx-linux/displaymod/1.0.0-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qmake -makefile -o Makefile  -r   /home/user1/oe-core/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-tdx-linux/displaymod/1.0.0-r1/guiframe.pro  --**

| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

**ERROR: Task (/home/user1/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-custom/recipes-custom/myqt/displaymod_1.0.0.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
**

i even checked my pkg-config and also my meta-layers and glib-2.0 is present

i want the image to be built and the t gui to come up on boot